# Don't load a relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Lets say I have a model like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
      attributes    : DS.attr('string'),
      countries     : DS.hasMany('country', { async: true }),
)};
```

And the server returns the JSON, with a `country_ids`array which all works fine, but I don't want to actually load the countries models corresponding to these IDs, which ember-data is doing automatically. Is there any way to stop/suppress this automatic functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data should load models only if you address to countries field.
If you need only ids try to define country_ids field in model.

UPD:

It seems like `*_ids` is reserved by framework. So you can ask your server to send this array with another name and define simple attr for this in model.
If you use rails and ActiveModel::Serializer it can be done like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids

  attributes :id, :attributes
  has_many :countries, key: :countries
end
```

And model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
      attributes    : DS.attr('string'),
      countries     : DS.attr()
)};
```

Comment: That seemed like a really good idea, but if I define `countryIds: DS.hasMany('country')` (or `country_ids`) with or without async I am just getting 0 for `countryIds.length`. Any idea why that might be? I am using ember-data 1.0.0 canary btw. Oh and thanks for the answer btw, it is really appreciated.